# How to gather facts after installing Python in one Ansible playbook?

Tags: python, ansible

I need to gather facts when executing my playbook. But the hosts have not installed Python yet.

If I gather facts first, the playbook will raise error because of lacking Python. If I install Python first, I have to set `gather_facts` to `no`.

How to gather facts after installing Python in one Ansible playbook?

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install Python 2.x
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt update && apt install -y python-simplejson)

  tasks:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setup` module.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install Python 2.x
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt update && apt install -y python-simplejson)

  tasks:
  - name: Get facts
    setup:

  - name: Other tasks.....
  ....
```

Documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html